# how to assign html option select value in php variable

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have designed option selection in html.

```
<select>
  <option value="e">Electronics</option>
  <option value="c">Clothing & Accessories</option>
 </select>
```

I want when i select Electronics. the electronic value should be assign to a php variable.when i select Clothing & Accessories. Clothing & Accessories should be assign to a php variable

Comment: you can done through ajax without ajax not possible.

Comment: your `select` tag does not have a `name` attribute...you need to give it one..then you can pick up the variable as you'd do for a `HTTP` request

Comment: If you have a complete html form set its action to the address of an php script, e.g. action="/form.php". Set method="post". Set name of select = "someName". Use $_POST array in php script to access values of your html select.

Comment: you can do it using form

Answer (score 0):

Use the select inside a form. And get the selected option by POST method.

```
<form action="#" method="POST">
 <select name="selection">
  <option value="e">Electronics</option>
  <option value="c">Clothing & Accessories</option>
 </select>
</form>
<?php 
$value = $_POST['selection']; // this $value variable contains the value of selected value.
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
 <?php
                if (!empty($_GET['dropdown'])) {
                    $dropdownval = $_GET['dropdown'];
                } else {
                    $dropdownval = 1;
                }
     ?>
        <form method="get" action="xyz.php">
        <select name="dropdown" >
        <option value="e" <?php if ($dropdownval=="e") echo 'selected="selected"'; ?>>Electronics </option>;
        <option value="c" <?php if ($dropdownval=="c") echo 'selected="selected"'; ?>>Clothing & Accessories</option>;
         </select>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit Form" />
        </form>
```